# Rails form_for pass params as Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page where I may add n number of questions. And my questions partial contains a form as follows:

```
= form_for :question, :url => questions_path do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
```

What I get in params is `"question"=>{"title"=>"Some Name"}`. But, if I click **Add New Question** button the same partial is rendered below. My problem is I still get the first questions params even if I have 2 forms now. Is there a way to get params like

```
"question"=>{["title"=>"Some Name"], ["title"=>"Some Other Name"]}
```

Comment: So you get n HTML forms in one page, right? I would have a collection of questions in the model. At every Add New Question I would add a new empty Question to the model and let the page render the list of questions in a single HTML form.

Comment: Yes, I'm willing to consolidate the params of all forms into one array so that I can iterate over them.

Comment: @Alex Its like I don't have questions predefined but are dynamically given by user. So I need to have array of questions and iterate over them to create records for each.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't receive all the inputs values on the server side if they are in several HTML forms in a single HTML page. Le's say you have two <form /> each having an <input />. A submit button can submit to the server a specific form, not both. Thus only the input value from that form is sent to the server (unless you have a javascript that read all data and... but this is not what you want).

Comment: "Its like I don't have questions predefined but are dynamically given by user." - that's fine. Still I would go with a model having a collection of questions. The very first time I would add a new empty Question to the model. The page will display it with empty inputs. Now Add New button adds a new empty Question to the model, and the page will show two questions, and so on. (Haven't tried this, but should work.)

Comment: @Alex Ok will try your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
= form_for :question, :url => questions_path do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, name: "question[title][]"
```

for more info refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters